# Sceneform ARCore load and build a random 3D asset

Tags: java, android, random, arcore, sceneform

I have a method that builds and spawns a 3D asset in an AR environment. The 3D asset is .sfb file stored in the metadata folder. I have multiple 3D assets in the metadata folder, and I wish to have an asset selected at random when this function is called. This is the code I have for spawning a specific asset:

```
private void addCreatureToScene() {

    ModelRenderable
            .builder()
            **.setSource(this, Uri.parse("20170219_Dragon_small.sfb"))**
            .build()
            .thenAccept(renderable -> {

                    Node node = new Node();
                    node.setRenderable(renderable);
                    scene.addChild(node);

                    Random random = new Random();
                    int x = random.nextInt(6);
                    int z = random.nextInt(6);
                    int y = random.nextInt(5);

                    z = -z;

                    node.setWorldPosition(new Vector3(
                            (float) x,
                            y / 10f,
                            (float) z
                    )); 
            });
}
```

The .setSource code in bold is where a specific 3D asset is referenced. Is there a way to randomly select a 3D asset from the metadata folder? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To help you simplify this problem, you should try to break it into smaller goals.
For example, here you are trying to:

1. Select a random file from a folder
2. Place that object in AR

Since you already have the 2nd step, the complicated step, figured, now look at the first step independent of it. The question you are asking is to select a random filename.

There are multiple ways to achieve this. The simplest one would be if you already know what all those filenames are, you can create a java list of those names, and then use `java.util.Random` to get one at random. More here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/randomly-select-items-from-a-list-in-java/

Else you will have to have a function to read all files in the folder and then randomly pick of those.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you kindly for your help! I decided to go with your final option of creating a function that reads all files and randomly picks one. Using the internet and compiling ideas, I came up with a function. No matter what I try, the File object keeps coming back as a null object reference. i.e., the file can't find the directory I am referencing. This is the declaration of the file:  final File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\mark\\HelloAR\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\"); and here is the error: final File f : folder.listFiles()